# Proving that group $G$ of order $|G|=35$ is Abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, sylow-theory

This is my outline of proof:

1. By Sylow's theorems, $G$ has two unique subgroups $H$ and $K$ respectively of order $5$ and order $7$ and both are Abelian; as groups of prime order are Abelian
2. Next I use the counting argument to say: Taking any $x\in{H}$ and $y\in{K}$ such that $x,y\notin{e}$, I will have more number of ordered pairs than the remaining elements in $G$ (i.e $35-5-7+1=24$)  ($e$ is common to both so $+1$)
3. Thus there are combinations which are same; implying $x$ and $y$ commute; but how do I proceed to prove that even the other elements commute. Kindly help in showing the way further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|G|=35$, then all of it elements must have order $1,5,7$ or $35$ by Lagrange.

The Sylow theorems shows that we have one subgroup $H$ of order $5$ and one subgroup $K$ of order $7$. Hence, we have $6$ elements of order $7$ and $4$ elements of order $5$.

So, by counting, $35 - 4 - 6 - 1 = 24$ elements of $G$ must have order $35$, then $G$ is cyclic, hence it's abelian.

Answer (score 4):

Let $h\in H, k\in K, [h,k]=hkh^{-1}k^{-1}=(hkh^{-1})k^{-1}=h(kh^{-1}k^{-1})$ is in $H\cap K$ since $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups, its order divides $5$ and $7$ so, it is $1$.

Comment: I am not sure how to use this infomation

Comment: @санкетмхаске Use it to deduce that $hk=kh$ for every $h\in H$ and $k\in K$.

Comment: $K$ is clearly a normal subgroup by the Sylow theorems. How do you prove that $H$ is? (Or, viewed another way: what part of this breaks down for $|G|=21$ rather than $|G|=35$?)

Comment: It looks like its based on Conjugacy classes which I am not introduced to yet. I will study more on this.@ArturoMagidin

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you figured out that the there are 24 elements left with order not $1,5,7$.  That implies the remaining elements must have order 35 (by Lagrange, I guess).

But if $G$ has an element of order $35$, then $G$ is isomorphic to the cyclic group $C_{35}$. Now, note that cyclic groups are indeed abelian.

Comment: I am not sure why remaining elements can't  have order 5/7. That is the gap in my understanding

Comment: Because you already showed that there is only one Sylow-5 subgroup and one Sylow-7 subgroup. If you had more elements of order 5 or 7, they would be generating another subgroup of order 5 or 7 and that contradicts that we had a unique Sylow subgroup.

Comment: Oh yes! How could I not see this. I am dumb sometimes. Thanks!